# How to dynamically pass a value into an iFrame using WKWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm trying to use an iFrame with WKWebView in order to load an embedded audio player that the streaming (host) website recommends.

When I pass the sound-track id dynamically, I get an error saying that the **audio is unavailable or has been deleted**. However, when I hard-code the sound-track id, it works perfectly fine and I can load the embedded player.

I want to know what is the correct way to pass a parameter dynamically to an iFrame, so that I can load the contents using a WKWebView (Swift 5/ iOS 13+)?

To summarize...

This does NOT work: (passing track-id dynamically)

```
htmlToLoad = "<iframe src=\"https://widget.podcastwebsite.com/player?track_id=\(track-id)\" width=\"100%\" height=\"50%\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"

webView.loadHTMLString(htmlToLoad!, baseURL: nil)
```

...

This works: (hard-coding track-id)

```
htmlToLoad = "<iframe src=\"https://widget.podcastwebsite.com/player?track_id=12345\" width=\"100%\" height=\"50%\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"

webView.loadHTMLString(htmlToLoad!, baseURL: nil)
```

The only difference between the two htmlToLoad variable is the way the track_id is being passed.

The flow of data is such that I download a playlist of tracks (through REST API calls) and then pass the track_id obtained (when a user would select a track) to load the iFrame (supplied by the host).

I've ensured that the variables are flowing through correctly and the value of the track-id is valid.

Appreciate any help that I could get.

Comment: Print the URL after merging track_id into a string and compare it with the working URL string.

Comment: Yes, the track_id is never set, it's always empty.

Comment: Good to see that you solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way that works,

instead of "(variable)": (old way)

```
htmlToLoad = "<iframe src=\"https://widget.podcastwebsite.com/player?track_id=\(track-id)\" width=\"100%\" height=\"50%\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"
```

I concatenated the variable: (new way)

```
htmlToLoad = "<iframe src=\"https://widget.podcastwebsite.com/player?track_id=" + track-id + "\" width=\"100%\" height=\"50%\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"
```

This works and holds the variable value.